# What is a "natural group action"?

Tags: calculus, group-theory, terminology, group-actions

Eg. The symmetric group on S acts on S in a natural way, for all sets S.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the action $Sym(S) \times S \to S$ given by $(f,x) \mapsto f(x)$.

Every action $G \times S \to S$ defines a homomorphism $G \to Sym(S)$ and vice-versa. The natural action defined above corresponds the identity homomorphism. This makes it "natural".

An "unnatural" group action $Sym(S) \times S \to S$ could for instance correspond to an nontrivial automorphism of $Sym(S)$ induced by renaming the elements of $S$.

Comment: Why is called natural?

Comment: @GPerez, because it's the first thing that comes to mind, isn't it? There is probably a precise statement in terms of categories.

Comment: I would say because every other actions on $S$ can (somehow) be seen as a sub-action of this one.

Comment: @lhf Yes, I was wondering if there was a technical definition though.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin, I've added a remark about this. Thanks.

Comment: @GPerez: The word "natural" has some technical usages in mathematics, particularly in category theory, but this is not one of them. The first comment of lhf hits the nail on the head: all "natural" means here is that from a group theoretic point of view, where an action is simply a homomorphism from some group to the group of permutations of some set, this is the simplest and first and "most natural" example.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you, I had glossed over some category theory, but only very leisurely. I recalled some definition of "natural" but I see now this is a different usage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"The natural action defined above corresponds the identity homomorphism"._ Which identity homomorphism? We have here homomorphisms from G to Sym(S), which are different groups. What is the "identity homomorphism" from one group to another? I can't make sense of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

For comparison's sake, we can try to build an "unnatural" group action.  Given a group $G$ and a set $S$, we know that the identity $e \in G$ must act as the identity map and that the action of two elements is the same as the action of their composition.

I propose as our "unnatural action" we take $S_n$ as our group and $S$ to be a set of $n$ labeled elements.  Then, instead of $(1,2) \in S_n$ transposing the $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ elements, it transposes the $5^{th}$ and $9^{th}$ elements.  There is certainly a way to make this a well-defined group action, but it doesn't feel natural at all.

Comment: In terms of my answer, this is using an automorphism of $S_n$ that is not the identity.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It helped me a lot :)